# Dynamically adding to Highcharts

Tags: javascript, json, api, highcharts

I have a json object which I am trying to add to my highcharts options.

I am able to recieve the object via API, and pass it to my highcharts function, But I am unable to add my data to the static data around it.

```
        var datas;
        datas = getData();
        //getdata();

        alert('2datass'+datas);
        console.log(datas);
        createChart(datas);


        function createChart(data){

            alert('createChart'+data); // works - outputs createChart[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]
            var dynamicData;


                    for(var i =0;i <= data.length-1;i++)
                    {
                        var item = data[i];

                        dynamicData = dynamicData + {
                            type: 'column',
                            name: item.name,
                            data: [item.difference]
                        };

                    }

            alert('dynamic' +dynamicData); // works, but says undefined before - outputs dynamic undefined[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]



            var series = [data /*This is where my data should sit*/,{
                    type: 'column',
                    name: 'Jane',
                    data: [300, 30]
                }, {
                    type: 'column',
                    name: 'John',
                    data: [-200, 50]
                }, {
                    type: 'column',
                    name: 'Joe',
                    data: [444, -25]
                }, {
                    type: 'column',
                    name: 'Jobe',
                    data: [444, -25]
                }, {
                    type: 'column',
                    name: 'Jooe',
                    data: [444, -25]
                },{
                    type: 'column',
                    name: 'Jane',
                    data: [300, 30]
                }
                , {
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Total consumption',
                    data: [{
                            name: 'Jane',
                            y: 13
                            //color: '#4572A7' // Jane's color
                        }, {
                            name: 'John',
                            y: 23
                            //color: '#AA4643' // John's color
                        }, {
                            name: 'Joe',
                            y: 19
                            //color: '#89A54E' // Joe's color
                        }],
                    center: [30, 80],
                    size: 100,
                    showInLegend: false,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }];




            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Account Managers Leaderboard'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Month on Month', 'Day on Day']
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        var s;
                        if (this.point.name) { // the pie chart
                            s = ''+
                                this.point.name +': '+ this.y +' sales';
                        } else {
                            s = ''+
                                this.x  +': '+ this.y;
                        }
                        return s;
                    }
                },
                labels: {
                    items: [{
                            html: 'Total proportion of sales <br />this month',
                            style: {
                                left: '40px',
                                top: '-5px',
                                color: 'black'
                            }
                        }]
                },
                series: series
            };

            $(document).ready(function() {
                var chart;
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });

        }



       function getData(){
            //alert('ajax');

            var receivedData; // store your value here
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "API URL",
                async: false,
                success: function(data){
                    alert('data'+data); //works
                    receivedData = data;
                }
            }); 

            return receivedData;
        };
```

My solution seems to be the wrong one as the dynamic data is not being added. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATED CODE:

```
 var dynamicData = {
                    type: 'column',
                    name: 'FIRST',
                    data: [300, 30]
                };

            //Without the following loop, my chart will display the above entry "FIRST"
            //With the loop, the chart omits everything in dynamicData
                    for(var i =0;i <= data.length-1;i++)
                    {
                        var item = data[i];

                        dynamicData = dynamicData + {
                            type: 'column',
                            name: item.name,
                            data: [item.difference]
                        };

                    }

            alert('dynamic' +dynamicData); // works, but says undefined before - outputs dynamic undefined[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]


                //dynamicData should be 'FIRST' and then 5 other returned rows
            var series = [dynamicData, {
                    type: 'column',
                    name: 'John',
                    data: [-200, 50]
                }, {
                    type: 'column',
                    name: 'Joe',
                    data: [444, -25]
                }, {
                    type: 'column',
                    name: 'Jobe',
                    data: [444, -25]
                }, {
                    type: 'column',
                    name: 'Jooe',
                    data: [444, -25]
                },{
                    type: 'column',
                    name: 'Jane',
                    data: [300, 30]
                }
                , {
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Total consumption',
                    data: [{
                            name: 'Jane',
                            y: 13
                            //color: '#4572A7' // Jane's color
                        }, {
                            name: 'John',
                            y: 23
                            //color: '#AA4643' // John's color
                        }, {
                            name: 'Joe',
                            y: 19
                            //color: '#89A54E' // Joe's color
                        }],
                    center: [30, 80],
                    size: 100,
                    showInLegend: false,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }];
```

AMENDED CODE, USING .push:

```
                // series has been moved straight into the options variable
                var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Account Managers Leaderboard'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Month on Month', 'Day on Day']
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        var s;
                        if (this.point.name) { // the pie chart
                            s = ''+
                                this.point.name +': '+ this.y +' sales';
                        } else {
                            s = ''+
                                this.x  +': '+ this.y;
                        }
                        return s;
                    }
                },
                labels: {
                    items: [{
                            html: 'Total proportion of sales <br />this month',
                            style: {
                                left: '40px',
                                top: '-5px',
                                color: 'black'
                            }
                        }]
                },
                series: [{
                        type: 'pie',
                        name: 'Total consumption',
                        data: [{
                                name: 'Jane',
                                y: 13
                                //color: '#4572A7' // Jane's color
                            }, {
                                name: 'John',
                                y: 23
                                //color: '#AA4643' // John's color
                            }, {
                                name: 'Joe',
                                y: 19
                                //color: '#89A54E' // Joe's color
                            }],
                        center: [30, 80],
                        size: 100,
                        showInLegend: false,
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }]
            };


            //I can now push data straight to seriese (although item.difference doesn't       
            // work .. perhaps because it's an array)

            for(var i =0;i <= data.length-1;i++)
            {
                var item = data[i];

                options.series.push({
                    "type": "column",
                    "name": item.name,
                    "data": item.data
                });
                alert('datavalue' +item.data);       
            }


               $(document).ready(function() {
                var chart;
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
```

ANSWER!

This seems to do the trick. Thank you to Speransky Danil for struggling along with me - much appreciated.

```
        var datas;
        datas = getData();
        createChart(datas);


        function createChart(data){

            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Account Managers Leaderboard'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Month on Month', 'Day on Day']
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        var s;
                        if (this.point.name) { // the pie chart
                            s = ''+
                                this.point.name +': '+ this.y +' sales';
                        } else {
                            s = ''+
                                this.x  +': '+ this.y;
                        }
                        return s;
                    }
                },
                labels: {
                    items: [{
                            html: 'Total proportion of sales <br />this month',
                            style: {
                                left: '40px',
                                top: '-5px',
                                color: 'black'
                            }
                        }]
                },
                series: [{
                        type: 'pie',
                        name: 'Total consumption',
                        data: [{
                                name: 'Jane',
                                y: 13
                                //color: '#4572A7' // Jane's color
                            }, {
                                name: 'John',
                                y: 23
                                //color: '#AA4643' // John's color
                            }, {
                                name: 'Joe',
                                y: 19
                                //color: '#89A54E' // Joe's color
                            }],
                        center: [30, 80],
                        size: 100,
                        showInLegend: false,
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }]
            };




            for(var i =0;i <= data.length-1;i++)
            {
                var item = data[i];

                options.series.push({
                    "type": "column",
                    "name": item.name,
                    "data": [item.data]
                });

            }



















            $(document).ready(function() {
                var chart;
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });

        }



        function getData(){
            //alert('ajax');

            var receivedData; // store your value here
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "API URL",
                async: false,
                success: function(data){
                    alert('data'+data); //works
                    receivedData = data;
                }
            }); 

            return receivedData;
        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the loop which contains:

```
dynamicData = dynamicData + {
   type: 'column',
   name: item.name,
   data: [item.difference]
};
```

First time `dynamicData` is `undefined`. When we sum `undefined` and  `Object` we convert both of them to `string` and concatinate it, so you get string `'undefined'[object Object]'`, then `'undefined[object Object][object Object]'` and so on *(converted to `string` object is `'[object Object]'`)*.

Comment: of course! Thank you.
It is no longer saying undefined .. but the data still isn't adding to the data series.

Comment: Updated in the original post at the bottom :)

Comment: The data looks like 
{
   type: 'column',
   name: 'Persons Name',
   data: [30]
}

I suspect I need to object.push, but I cannot seem to do that on a json object that has no parent. (i.e parent : {
   type: 'column',
   name: 'Persons Name',
   data: [30]
}

Comment: What's JavaScript?

I would, primarily, appreciate help on adding values to a JSON object. Perhaps we could save the rhetorical questions for after?

This is an open platform for those needing help and those wishing to contribute, I hope you don't feel pressured to help if unable to.

I am more than happy to struggle on :)

Comment: getData() returns " [object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object] " these are what I wish to add to my dataseries

Comment: the data from my API is outputted as. [{"type":"Column","name":"A Name","user_id":1,"data":["-0.42",0]},{"type":"Column","name":"A Name","user_id":4,"data":["0.28",0]},{"type":"Column","name":"A Name","user_id":14,"data":["-0.09",0]},{"type":"Column","name":"A Name","user_id":15,"data":["-0.04",0]},{"type":"Column","name":"A Name","user_id":16,"data":["-0.61",0]}] - the field "user_id" is not needed in highcharts .. but when I manually add it, highcharts omits .. so this can be ignored.

Comment: var series = [{
                    type: 'column',
                    name: 'FIRST',
                    data: [300, 30]
                }, {
                    type: 'column',
                    name: 'A name',
                    data: [-0.61, 0]
                }, {
                    type: 'column',
                    name: 'A name',
                    data: [-0.61, 0]
                }, {
                    type: 'column',
                    name: 'A name',
                    data: [-0.61, 0]
                }, etc..

Comment: Yes, which is why I believe I need to push the values into the object, as mentioned above. If I thought I could simply prepend as I am currently doing then I wouldn't have bothered looping around my data and saving to 'dynamicData' when I could just have inserted 'data'.

Comment: unfortunately not, because Series goes on a lot longer than that (check original code). I have created a solution using .push, everything seems to work except for the actual value (item.difference). Check Original post for ammended code.

Comment: It was being passed as a string through the API for some reason. All sorted! thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do the trick. Thank you to Speransky Danil for struggling along with me - much appreciated.

```
        var datas;
        datas = getData();
        createChart(datas);


        function createChart(data){

            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Account Managers Leaderboard'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Month on Month', 'Day on Day']
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        var s;
                        if (this.point.name) { // the pie chart
                            s = ''+
                                this.point.name +': '+ this.y +' sales';
                        } else {
                            s = ''+
                                this.x  +': '+ this.y;
                        }
                        return s;
                    }
                },
                labels: {
                    items: [{
                            html: 'Total proportion of sales <br />this month',
                            style: {
                                left: '40px',
                                top: '-5px',
                                color: 'black'
                            }
                        }]
                },
                series: [{
                        type: 'pie',
                        name: 'Total consumption',
                        data: [{
                                name: 'Jane',
                                y: 13
                                //color: '#4572A7' // Jane's color
                            }, {
                                name: 'John',
                                y: 23
                                //color: '#AA4643' // John's color
                            }, {
                                name: 'Joe',
                                y: 19
                                //color: '#89A54E' // Joe's color
                            }],
                        center: [30, 80],
                        size: 100,
                        showInLegend: false,
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }]
            };




            for(var i =0;i <= data.length-1;i++)
            {
                var item = data[i];

                options.series.push({
                    "type": "column",
                    "name": item.name,
                    "data": [item.data]
                });

            }



















            $(document).ready(function() {
                var chart;
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });

        }



        function getData(){
            //alert('ajax');

            var receivedData; // store your value here
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "http://a-website.com/apiv1/summery/get/authKey/1/range/day/",
                async: false,
                success: function(data){
                    alert('data'+data); //works
                    receivedData = data;
                }
            }); 

            return receivedData;
        };
```