# Plotting data using higcharts in flask web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, highcharts, flask

I am trying to plot data from mysql server and display it in a web server. I am using highcharts javascript library for plotting. I can get data from mysql database and data is sent from server-side to client-side as json data. Then by using highcharts I want to display it. But chart shows nothing when I try to plot.

Here is important snippet code in server side (I am using AJAX):

```
def background_process():
    start = request.form['name_start']
    finish = request.form['name_finish']
    df_sorted = mutechDataManipulate.sort_by_time(df, pd.to_datetime(str(start)), pd.to_datetime(str(finish)), 'Date')
    print df_sorted['Date'].head()
    df_out_json = df_sorted[['Date', 'High']].to_json(orient='values')
    return json.dumps(df_out_json)
```

Here is client side (I get json data from server successfully):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on("click", "#btn1", function() {       
    console.log("alii");
    var user = $('input[name="name_start"]').val();
    var pass = $('input[name="name_finish"]').val();
    console.log("sivgin");      
    $.ajax({
        url: '/background_process',
        data: $("form").serialize(),
        type: "POST",
        success: function(response) {
            $('#result').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'High'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'area',
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: response
                }]
         });
            console.log(response)
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Finally, I get a blank graph like this:

[image: empty chart]

In addition I try to plot time series line chart. What is wrong?

Edit: Forgot to html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Mutech</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/js/script.js"></script>
  <script src="static/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<br/>
<div class="container">  
  <form class="form-inline" id="form1"  method="post" >
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Start Date</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="id_start" name ="name_start">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Finish Date</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="id_finish" name ="name_finish">
    </div>
    <br/><br/>
    <br/>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id= "btn1">Submit</button>

  </form>
</div>

<div class="container" id = "result">
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since the chart is empty, it most probably has no data to show. Check your AJAX call. Try getting the data and displaying it in a div. It will help with debugging. I encountered a very similar issue, turned out that my chart settings weren't right. It would also help if you can post the console error messages here :)

Comment: Actually there are no error messages, everything looks fine and i can see data on console. :)

Comment: How your response data looks?

Comment: [[1285632000000,null],[1285545600000,25.39]]
something like this. first date in miliseconds and then value @Grzegorz Blachliński

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look your data is formatted correctly for Highcharts.  If you look at [this other StackOverlow question about JSON data and Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643609/how-to-pass-json-data-to-highcharts-series) you'll see that the data should be a list of dictionaries.

To do this why pandas, you pass the value `"records"` into the `orient` option.

```
df_out_json = df_sorted[['Date', 'High']](orient="records")
#[{"Date":1285632000000, "High":None}, {"Date":1285545600000, "High":25.39}]
```

See more in the [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) for `to_json`.

Comment: I changed orient and it gave me response data like this:
[{\"Date\":1285632000000,\"High\":null},{\"Date\":1285545600000,\"High\":25.39}]

But nothing has change. @Jalepeno112

Comment: I think that you may try using 'y' instead of 'High'.

Comment: i think the problem is json string. the response data is string an i have to convert it number with javascript or some other way. because i am new at javascript , i don't know how to do this.